# How do I change the font embeddability?

Tags: css, fonts

I want to change the embeddability of a font I purchased online, the current embeddability is "print and preview" but I want to make it "editable".

How do I change it?

Comment: You go to the font vendor and purchase the correct licence.

Answer (score 0):

You need to talk to the developer of the font from whom you licensed it to see if they are willing to give you a license with different embedding permissions.

Comment: To be clear about the answer I provided: changing the embedding metadata in the font may be (or probably is) in violation of the license: if the font vendor was providing a license that allowed for editable embedding, they likely would have indicated that in the font already. I'm not going to provide an answer to facilitate someone violating the license.